# Accepting only integer in C

Tags: c

How do you propose I write my code to accept only integers in C and if a letter is entered, prompt to enter only integers? And Vice versa. 
`printf("Enter integer");
scanf("%d", &a);`

Answer (score 2):

```
while(scanf("%d", &a)==0) //if scanf failed to scan an integer
{
    printf("Invalid input. Try again\n");
    int c;
    while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF); //clear the stdin
}
```